# Closed-form solution for an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

Is there a closed form solution for the following integral

$$\int_0^z\frac{1}{1+z-x}\frac{1}{(1+x)^K}\,dx$$

for a positive integer $K\geq 1$, and positive real number $z\geq 0$? I searched the table of integrals, but couldn't find something similar.

Comment: Aside from looking at a table of similar integrals, what have you tried yourself? It is recommend you include [more context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) than the question itself. For example, why would you expect there to be a solution? Have you tried solving it for, say, $K=1,2,3$?

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution. I want to know if I have to evaluate it numerically, or there are some tricks I can try. How can I evaluate it for low $K$? Using integration by parts?

Comment: For small values of $K$ you can use partial fraction decompositions.

Comment: In the same spirit as partial fractions, note that$$\frac{2+z}{(1+z-x)(1+x)^K}=\frac{(1+x)+(1+z-x)}{(1+z-x)(1+x)^K}$$which gives a nice recursive equation for the integral...

Comment: In this case I need to solve $K+1$ linear equations to find the coefficients. Right? Suppose the coefficients are $A$, and $B_k$, so the integral can be written as $$A\int_0^z(1+z-x)^{-1}\,dx +\sum_{k=1}^KB_k\int_0^z(1+x)^{-k}\,dx$$, right? Where is the recursion you are mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $$ I(k)=\frac {1}{z+2} \int_0^z \frac {(1+x)+(1+z-x)}{(1+z-x)(1+x)^k} dx $$

$$I(k)=\frac {1}{z+2} \int_0^z \frac{1}{(1+z-x)(1+x)^{k-1}}+\frac {1}{z+2}\int_0^z (1+x)^{-k}$$

Therefore $$I(k)=\frac {I(k-1)}{z+2} +\frac {(1+z)^{1-k}-1}{(1-k)(z+2)}$$

If you now want then you can solve this recursion but I don't think that would be a great and easy job to do.

Hope it helps

Comment: Interesting. But is it necessary to solve it like this? Isn't writing it as $$A\int_0^z(1+z-x)^{-1}\,dx +\sum_{k=1}^KB_k\int_0^z(1+x)^{-k}\,dx$$ is easier to solve, after finding the coefficients? I see maybe the solution using recursion won't involve complex functions such as Hypergeometric function, is this correct?

Comment: @BlackMath. I think that it depends very much on what you want to do with it. As it is, the recursion given by Manthanein is very nice from a formal point of view. If you want to code the problem for given $K$ and $z$, I guess that using the $ _2\tilde{F}_1\left(.\right)$ would be more efficient.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I want to find the original integral in compact form, in terms of functions that are built-in in software like MATLAB, to find the solution efficiently for a given $K$ and $z$.

Comment: @BlackMath Then I guess,  using the hypergeometric  functions would be the way to go if you want only a compact form at the end

Comment: @Manthanein Yes, I want a compact form at the end. I will get the hypergeometric function from solving the integrals $$A\int_0^z(1+z-x)^{-1}\,dx +\sum_{k=1}^KB_k\int_0^z(1+x)^{-k}\,dx$$, right? The question arises then: is there a way to solve for the coefficients by a software, without having to find $K+1$ linear equations manually?

Comment: If I had the following twist $$\int_0^z\frac{1}{1+\min(x,\,z-x)}\frac{1}{(1+x)^K}\,dx$$, how could I evaluate the integral then? I found the solution for each argument ##x## and ##z-x## of the `min` function, but based on what I would select either in the numerical simulation?

Comment: @BlackMath Won't be tough even now. Write it as $$J(k)=\int_0^{z/2} \frac {1}{(1+x)^{k+1}}dx +\int_{z/2}^{z} \frac {1}{(z-x)(1+x)^{k}} dx$$ The first one is easy  and repeat the similar process as in the original answer for the second one.

Comment: @Manthanein I think the last integral in your answer should be $\int_0^z (1+x)^{-k} \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{(1+z)^{1-k} - 1}{1-k}$ (and a logarithm for $k=1$ of course).

Comment: @Manthanein Thanks. I searched the Table of Integrals, and there is no integral in the form $$\int_a^b(1+x)^{-k}\,dx$$  but there is an integral in the form $$\int_a^{\infty}(1+x)^{-k}\,dx$$ So, I think we can write $$\int_a^b(1+x)^{-k}\,dx = \int_a^{\infty}(1+x)^{-k}\,dx - \int_b^{\infty}(1+x)^{-k}\,dx$$

Comment: @Manthanein In your answer, how did find that $$\int_0^z (1+x)^{-k}\,dx = \frac {(1+z)^{1-k}+(-1)^{k}}{(1-k)}$$?

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial Yeah thanks. Edited accordingly

Comment: @BlackMath Hint::Use the substitution $t=1+x$

Comment: @Manthanein Thanks. That was elegant. After some thinking, I think using the recursive method is more appropriate for an arbitrary $K$, because I can write a dynamic code for that (a recursive function). Otherwise, I need to hard code the $K+1$ linear equations for each choice of $K$ and solve them.